# Chrome redrawing canvas on printing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm finding a very annoying behaviour on Chrome.

I've a page where I'm using a js graph library to build Gantt diagrams with vacation days of company workers.

The library uses HTML5 canvas to draw the graph, and the page just loads data based on date and department parameters and feeds the library methods.

Both, Firefox and Chrome, work perfectly and draws the Gantt diagrams as expected, however, when I try to print it, I find that Chrome changes the diagram if I alter any of printing attributes on page configuration dialog.

Also, after closing printing dialog, the graph on the page gets also changed.

Printing in Firefox hasn't any effect on the page and doesn't redraws the graph when changing printing parameters.

I've been looking for info into this on internet but found nothing except a maybe related bug on Chrome from 2014 that seems to be fixed.

I'm a bit lose with this and would appreciate any insight on the matter.